# vuejs - "editing" html inside variable

Tags: vue.js

I've got a variable which has html inside. This is for my wysiwyg editor.

```
data () {
  return {
     HTMLtext: "<p style="text-align: center;"><b>Hospital</b></p><p> 
       </p><p style="text-align: center;"> <b>Physician</b></p>
       <p></p><p style="text-align: center;"> City <b>New York</b>",
     Place: "London"
   }
 }
```

Now, I want to change this HTMLtext variable in some places. For example I've got variable called place:

```
Place: "London"
```

and I want to replace `<b>New York</b>` with `Place` variable into `<b>London</b>`

What should I do? 
What is the best approach? 
Is it generally safe? 
Is this a good practice?

Comment: Generally, no, it's not safe to make arbitrary edits to HTML, and it isn't clear how you would decide to replace, specifically, `<b>New York</b>`. Can you give us some more description of how this step fits into what you're trying to do?

Comment: @RoyJ The first problem is just that: how to replace this part of HTML code.
The second, later on, how to sanitize Place variable.
I want to make my variables reusable, so my user don't need to type them again. It's not a rocket science, so it should be possible :)

Comment: I would probably make HTMLtext a computed that returns a template string that substitutes in data items, like `...<p style="text-align: center;"> City <b>${this.Place}</b>`

Comment: how to do that? I didn't know about `${this.Place}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you make `HTMLtext` a [computed](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html), it can compose the text based on the variables. [Template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) are a nice way to interpolate variables into strings.

Here's an example of what I'm suggesting. I don't know if that will work in your circumstance because I don't know where HTMLtext comes from or how you know that New York is in it to be replaced.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    place: 'New York'
  },
  computed: {
    htmlText() {
      return `<p style="text-align: center;"><b>Hospital</b></p><p> 
       </p><p style="text-align: center;"> <b>Physician</b></p>
       <p></p><p style="text-align: center;"> City <b>${this.place}</b>`;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  Place: <input v-model="place">
  <div v-html="htmlText"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'll try it, it seems to be the right way. Thank you for your help!